# An a example of a convergent series such that ...

Tags: real-analysis

An a example of a convergent series $\sum a_{n}$ and a bounded sequence ($x_{n}$) such that the series $\sum a_{n}x_{n}$ divergent

Comment: "An a example of a convergent series ∑an and a bounded sequence (xn) such that the series ∑anxn divergent" OK, and what is your question?

Comment: because I need an example of this and with the series and successions I have tried do not give me divergent

Comment: "with the series and successions I have tried" Such as?

Comment: Try looking at a conditionally convergent series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternating harmonic series $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} = \ln(2)$$ converges, while the sequence $x_n =\{ (-1)^{n+1} \} $ is bounded as it oscillates between $1$ and $-1$.

Their term-by-term product gives the harmonic series $$\sum_{k=1} ^{\infty} \frac{1}{k}$$ which diverges.